# Where can I learn more about 孔明點將?

Tags: texts

A relative of mine did some kind of praying ritual in front of a Buddha where she had a canister of 100 or so sticks, and on each stick there is a Chinese number from 1 to 100.  My relative started shaking the canister and eventually stick number 9 fell out.  My relative and I both do not speak or write chinese.  But apparently, she is supposed to read about 孔明點將, which is related to stick number 9.

Where can I get an English description/story of stick 9 孔明點將 ?

Also, we do not know anything about Buddhism. So if you can recommend any brief literature that might help with the context of stick 9 孔明點將 , that would be great.

Comment: Google translates it as "Ming points"

Comment: @SankhaKulathantille there's supposed to be a whole story behind it. The google translator and chrome translator does a really poor job explaining and giving context.

Answer (score 1):

I found the translation here:
http://accesschinese.com/divination/guanyin/your-lot.php?tile=9

Now that I read it, I don't think it has anything to do with Buddhism

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially from a Chinese divination ritual, in many Chinese shrines and temples, believers often have personal questions needing answers from the divine and one 'solution' to getting an answer is to perform a 'divination ceremony' through random chances by shaking a canister of sticks until one falls out. Each one is labeled with a number and you find your corresponding slip of message. (Similar divination rituals such as the I Ching utilize chance for the same purpose). The canister one is essentially a simple version of that. Basically 'Buddhist' fortune cookies.

As we can see, the messages found in these are generally wisdom that are applicable across a whole range of situations, and therefore it is essentially a way of self reflection.

From John's link:
"Yield not to greed and hate; cast them aside. Let conscience be your only guide. Your heart will be open, pure, sublime and bright. Just like the full moon that shines high in the sky."

So this is essentially a form of skillful means to preach the message of Buddhism to the simple often desperate masses.